# How to manage elements of other row while sorting some particular row?

Tags: c++, sorting

given a 2D array for eg.

```
int  arr[2][5] = { {5 , 3 , 4 , 1 , 2},{7 , 4 , 0 , 8 , 2}};
```

now I am sorting first row in ascending order and correspondingly 2nd row elements are also shifted.
altered 2D array

```
int arr[2][5] = { {1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5},{8 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 7}};
```

I am using heapsort algo for acheiving this but i have to write whole code everytime.
I want to know some way to acheive this using c++ standard functions.
plzz someone help me out on this :)

Answer (score 0):

With the current algorithms you'd need to "zip" the two ranges into a common view of elements from both ranges ordered according to the key of the first range. Creating a corresponding random access iterator is mostly straight forward except for the somewhat unfortunate constraint that `operator*()` is supposed to yield a reference to the respective elements.

I think Boost has a zip-range providing the corresponding functionality.